# Database does not get updated, But no error appears. MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a website for a friend and basically I have 15 fields that are editable depending on the user type. Basically my code is echoing the row out on to the field, but when when I go to change it and update the database nothing happens. I don't receive any error messages, so i'm thinking it's something to do with my condition statements. My functions work fine, how ever my query doesn't seem to like me.

```
<?php
//end of function
}

// connect to the database
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$database = 'bubbles';

//Connect to the database
$connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die ("Could not connect to server ... \n" . mysql_error ());

//Select the database name
$select = mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Could not connect to database ... \n" . mysql_error ());

// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{ 

    // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
    if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
    {

        //Get form data to make sure it's valid
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
        $dueDate = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['dueDate']));
        $numOfPages = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['numOfPages']));
        $numOfCopies = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['numOfCopies']));
        $paperSize = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['paperSize']));
        $paperColor = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['paperColor']));
        $weight = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['weight']));
        $finishing = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['finishing']));
        $paymentMethod = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['paymentMethod']));
        $printColor = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['printColor']));
        $status = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['status']));
        $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']));

        // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
        if ($name == '' || $dueDate == '' || $numOfPages == '' || $numOfCopies == '' || $comment == '')
        {
            // generate error message
            $error = 'Please fill in all required fields!';

            //error, display form
            displayForm($id,
                       $name,
                       $dueDate,
                       $numOfPages,
                       $numOfCopies,
                       $paperSize,
                       $paperColor,
                       $weight,
                       $finishing,
                       $paymentMethod,
                       $printColor,
                       $comment,
                       $status,
                       $error);
        }
        else
        {

            //Insert form data into the database or die if there is an error
        print $sql;

        $sql = ("UPDATE orders SET `name` = '".$name."',
                                   due_date = '".$dueDate."',
                                   numOfPages = '".$numOfPages."',
                                   numOfCopies = '".$numOfCopies."',
                                   paper_size = '".$paperSize."',
                                   paper_color = '".$paperColor."',
                                   weight = '".$weight."',
                                   finishing = '".$finishing."',
                                   payment_method = '".$paymentMethod."',
                                   color = '".$printColor."',
                                   comments = '".$comment."',
                                  `status` = '".$status."' WHERE id = '".$id."'");

        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

            // once saved, redirect back to the view page
            header("Location: http://localhost/Bubbles/view-orders.php"); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
        echo 'Error!';
    }
}
else
{
    // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form

    // get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid 
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
    {
        // query db
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
        if($row)
        {

            // get data from db
            $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $dueDate = $row['due_date'];
            $numOfPages = $row['numOfPages'];
            $numOfCopies = $row['numOfCopies'];
            $paperSize = $row['paper_size'];
            $paperColor = $row['paper_color'];
            $weight = $row['weight'];
            $finishing = $row['finishing'];
            $paymentMethod = $row['payment_method'];
            $printColor = $row['color'];
            $status = $row['status'];
            $comment = $row['comments'];

            // show form
            displayForm($id,
                       $name,
                       $dueDate,
                       $numOfPages,
                       $numOfCopies,
                       $paperSize,
                       $paperColor,
                       $weight,
                       $finishing,
                       $paymentMethod,
                       $printColor,
                       $comment,
                       $status,
                       '');
        }
        else
        {
            // if no match, display result
            echo "No results!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
        echo 'Error!';
    }
}
?>
```

Updated with HTML

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action"" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
    <div class="floatLeft">
                    <p>Name:                            <br /> <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/></p>
                    <p>Due Date (ex: yyyy-mm-dd):       <br /> <input type="datetime" name="dueDate" value="<?php echo $dueDate; ?>" /></p>
                    <p># of Pages                       <br /> <input type="number" name="numOfPages" value="<?php echo $numOfPages; ?>"/></p>
                    <p># of Copies                      <br /> <input type="number" name="numOfCopies" value="<?php echo $numOfCopies; ?>"/></p>
                </div>
                <div class="floatLeft"> 
                    <p>Paper Size<br /> 
                    <select name = "paperSize" value="<?php echo $paperSize; ?>">
                        <option value="8.5 x 11in">8.5 x 11 inches</option>
                        <option value="8.5 x 14in">8.5 x 14 inches</option>
                        <option value="11 x 17in">11 x 17 inches</option>
                    </select>           
                    </p>
                    <p>Paper Color<br /> 
                    <select name = "paperColor" value="<?php echo $paperColor; ?>">
                        <option value = "pulsar pink">Pulsar Pink</option>
                        <option value = "fireball fuchsia">Fireball Fuchsia</option>
                        <option value = "plasma pink">Plasma Pink</option>
                        <option value = "re-entry red">Re-entry Red</option>
                        <option value = "rocket red">Rocket Red</option>
                        <option value = "cosmic orange">Cosmic Orange</option>
                        <option value = "galaxy gold">Galaxy Gold</option>
                        <option value = "solar yellow">Solar Yellow</option>
                        <option value = "venus violet">Venus Violet</option>
                        <option value = "planetary purple">Planetary Purple</option>
                        <option value = "celestial blue">Celestial Blue</option>
                        <option value = "lunar blue">Lunar Blue</option>
                        <option value = "gamma green">Gamma Green</option>
                        <option value = "martian green">Martian Green</option>
                        <option value = "terra green">Terra Green</option>
                        <option value = "lift-off lemmon">Lift-off Lemon</option>
                    </select>           
                    </p>
                    <p>Weight<br/> 
                    <select name = "weight" value="<?php echo $weight; ?>">
                    <option value="20lbs">20lbs</option>
                    <option value="60lbs">60lbs</option>
                    <option value="65lbs">65lbs</option>
                    </select>           
                    </p>
                    <p>Finishing<br /> 
                <select name = "finishing" value="<?php echo $finishing; ?>">
                    <option value="none">None</option>
                    <option value="cutting">Cutting</option>
                    <option value="folding">Folding</option>
                    <option value="quaters">Quaters</option>
                    <option value="binding">Bindings</option>
                </select>           
                </p>
                <p>Payment method<br /> 
                <select name = "paymentMethod" value="<?php echo $paymentMethod; ?>">
                    <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
                    <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
                    <option value="Check">Check</option>
                    <option value="Wilscard">Wilscard</option>
                </select>           
                </p>
                <p>Print BW/C<br /> 
                <select name = "printColor" value="<?php echo $printColor; ?>">
                    <option value="Black">Black</option>
                    <option value="White">White</option>
                    <option value="Color">Color</option>
                </select>
                </p>            
                </p>
                </div>
                <div class="floatLeft">
                <p>Status<br /> 
                <select name = "status" value="<?php echo $row['status']; ?>">
                    <option value="Recieved">Received</option>
                    <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                    <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                </select>   
                <p>Comment (Cannot exceed 200 characters):<br />
                <textarea name="comment" value="<?php echo $comment; ?>"></textarea><br />
                </p>
                <input type="submit" value="Edit Order" />
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

UPDATE: I fixed the code, thanks everyone for all the help, but my error was that  when I check the empty field, there was nothing written in the comment box so it was thinking all fields were empty when in reality they weren't. i updated the field check with this code and it works fine now.

I updated the if statement from this:

```
if ($name == '' || $dueDate == '' || $numOfPages == '' || $numOfCopies == '' || $comment == '')
```

To this:

```
if ($name == '' || $dueDate == '' || $numOfPages == '' || $numOfCopies == '')
```

Comment: i think you don't fire update query at all after storing it in '$sql' variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're running the query after you create it in the $sql variable. You'll want to execute the query like you do later in the code:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will return `true` on success or `false` (and die) on failure.

Comment: Wow I feel really dumb it's 1:00 am here haha. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Haha, it happens. Just needs another pair of eyes.

Lea is also right, it looks like the syntax on your update statement is a bit off (missing SET).

Answer (score 0):

If you execute your **UPDATE** sql statement should give you some **ERROR** (since you forgot **SET**). However, you are not executing it. Once you fix that issue, you need to change your **UPDATE** statement to

```
$sql = "UPDATE orders 
SET 
    `name` = '".$name."',
    due_date = '".$dueDate."',
    numOfPages = '".$numOfPages."',
    numOfCopies = '".$numOfCopies."',
    paper_size = '".$paperSize."',
    paper_color = '".$paperColor."',
    weight = '".$weight."',
    finishing = '".$finishing."',
    payment_method = '".$paymentMethod."',
    color = '".$printColor."',
    comments = '".$comment."',
    `status` = '".$status."'
WHERE
    id = '".$id."'";
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

**Note:** I escaped `name` and `status` columns since their are reserved words

Comment: I updated the code and still nothing happens.. In my website I am able to add, remove and view orders but I am unable to edit. I'll post some html in a minute.

Comment: I found an issue with your and my code, single quotes will treat variables as string

Comment: I edited my answer. And if for some reason it does not work before you execute your query `print $sql;` and try to execute it directly (terminal, mysql workbench, sqlyog, phpmyadmin or your favourite application)

Comment: updated my code. and i don't know why it doesn't want to work. i triple checked my field values and they are all correct. no misspelling or anything. the table displays fine and it catches the rows fine. but does not edit any thing.

Comment: did you try to print the `$sql` value? did you try to execute it?

Comment: i added the print sql value but i didn't go to execute it.. where do i go in phpmyadmin to add it?

Comment: You have to go to SQL tab and paste the sql query and click GO button. Btw, what is the value of sql?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query it may solve your problem:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE orders set name ='".$name."' set due_date = '".$dueDate."' set numOfPages = '".$numOfPages."' set numOfCopies = '".$numOfCopies."' set paper_size = '".$paperSize."' set paper_color = '".$paperColor."' set weight = '".$weight."' set finishing = '".$finishing."' set payment_method = '".$paymentMethod."' set color = '".$printColor."' set comments = '".$comment."' set status = '".$status."' WHERE id = '".$id."' ";
```